# How to force one script to load before google tag manager script

Tags: functions, order, scripts, google

I have configured a cookie consent banner called OneTrust to block cookies like google tag manager unless the user accepts the cookies.

The onetrust script should load just after the head tag and I placed it there, however, google tag scripts jump to the top of the head.

I have tried to use functions like this below, and give priorities but it didn't work.

the site: https://www.staycity.com/

```
add_action('wp_head', 'onetrust_add_script_wp_head',0);
function onetrust_add_script_wp_head() {
    ?>
<script src="https://optanon.blob.core.windows.net/langswitch/d1d83e3b-52b4-470c-abde-3535ef8b3e06.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function OptanonWrapper() { }
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action('wp_head', 'gtm_add_script_wp_head',999);
function gtm_add_script_wp_head() {
    ?>
  <script>
    (function(a, s, y, n, c, h, i, d, e) {
        s.className += ' ' + y;
        h.start = 1 * new Date;
        h.end = i = function() {
            s.className = s.className.replace(RegExp(' ?' + y), '')
        };
        (a[n] = a[n] || []).hide = h;
        setTimeout(function() {
            i();
            h.end = null
        }, c);
        h.timeout = c;
    })(window, document.documentElement, 'async-hide', 'dataLayer', 4000, {
        'GTM-P9QMT3': true
    });
    </script>
    <!-- END: Anti-flicker snippet (GOptimize)  -->
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Try [enqueuing your scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/), then you can control the order.

Comment: But how to include a script code in wp_enqueue_script?

Comment: Read the documentation I linked to?